# Trying to use multiprocessing over files but freezes when I have the user input a path

Tags: python, csv, multiprocessing

I'm pretty new to Python, and I'm working on an assignment where multiprocessing is a requirement. I have a folder with a few .csv files in it and I want output of the form [file name, gradient, intercept] for each file in the folder. I can get this to work using a for loop, and the multiprocessing works when I put the file names manually into the code, like this:

```
import numpy
import os
import csv
from multiprocessing import Pool

files_txt = ['Data_set_1.csv','Data_set_2.csv','Data_set_3.csv','Data_set_4.csv']
print("files: ",files_txt)
lines = []
def GetLines(name):
    f = open(name)
    csv_f = csv.reader(f)
    csv_x = []
    csv_y = []
    for row in csv_f:
        try:
            csv_x.append(float(row[0]))
            csv_y.append(float(row[1]))
        except ValueError:
            pass
    f.close()
    x = numpy.array(csv_x)
    y = numpy.array(csv_y)
    m, b = numpy.polyfit(x, y, 1)
    lines.append([name,m,b])
    return lines
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes = 2)
    result = pool.map(GetLines,files_txt)
    print(result)
```

This gives me my desired output, however when I change the first line to:

```
path = input("path: ")
files = os.listdir(path)
files_txt = [a for a in files if a.endswith(".csv")]
```

It prints out the names of my files in the folder and then just does nothing.
I have no idea how to remedy this and I've been googling all night.

Comment: Trying to handle interactive I/O in a multiprocessing context is tricky.  Is there a reason you need to take the path names interactively?  If it were me I would just pass the filenames at the command-line, e.g. `./name-of-script.py file1.csv file2.csv file3.csv`.  This is better anyways because it can be used as part of a pipeline and can take advantage of features of your shell like wildcard (`./name-of-script.py *.csv`).

Comment: @Iguananaut The interactive I/O as described by the OP is not inside the multiprocessing section but before the `pool.map` is entered. I suspect that this is an issue that the filenames need to be converted to full paths.

Comment: By the way, I noticed you're using the standard Python `csv` module to read CSV files and convert their contents to Numpy arrays.  Numpy has built-in functions for doing this and it will probably be more efficient. E.g. [`np.loadtxt`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html#numpy.loadtxt).  Use like `x, y = np.loadtxt(filename, delmiter=',').T`

Comment: @alaniwi Depending on the OS or process spawn method, each sub-process might re-import the module and run module-level code (e.g. if not using `fork()`).  But you're right this wouldn't necessarily cause a hang, it just means the `input()` would be called for each sub-process (still not what you want).  A different error can sometimes cause multiprocessing to hang though.

Comment: @Iguananaut It's certainly better if the `input` is put in the `if __name__ == '__main__':` section and not at the top. From what you're saying, it may even be critically important. Actually, this must be the issue.  Okay, _separately_, full paths are needed. (I couldn't see why this would cause a hang, and it sounds like the reason why it's hanging is that you have an `input` happening inside the workers during the re-import.)

Comment: So, two issues to fix, I think: (1) move those first three lines that you added in place of the `files_txt =` to just under the `if __name__ == '__main__':` (with appropriate indentation), and (2), change the last of them to `files_txt = [os.path.join(path, a) for a in files if a.endswith(".csv")]` - and see how you get on...

Comment: @alaniwi putting it under the if __name__ part totally fixed it, thankyou!

Comment: You should still pass your path via command-line arguments instead of an interactive prompt.  It will be much more convenient.